# How can I load a files into a project so that I can open it on any machines without having to correct the file pathway? (working on PYcharm)

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, raspberry-pi, pycharm

I'm working on a small personal project at the moment, where the user will input a string to look for into a given .txt file, and if the string is found, the program will display the next substring. I've got the core part figured out.

but I'm coding on my main computer but want to run this app on a raspberry-Pi, and I'm quite lost as how I could include the file into the directory and makes my pathway from within the directory to import and open the file. So here I am asking your help on that matter!

something strange is happening when I try to open the .txt files, pycharm tells me:

```
C:\Users\xavie\PycharmProjects\untitled1\venv\Scripts\python.exe "C:\Users\xavie\PycharmProjects\untitled1\dico\Dictionnaire Mandoa.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\xavie\PycharmProjects\untitled1\dico\Dictionnaire Mandoa'.py", line 1, in <module>
    f=open('dicotest.txt','r')
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'dicotest.txt'
```

while I do have the said files as this screenshot  shows[screenshot of repository](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ogGd.jpg)

Comment: You should look into the os.path module
https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html

Comment: thanks I will look into that!

Answer (score 0):

So I found a work around: placing it directly in the same folder as my `.py` file. It is not a "clean" way since it seems I can't run this script out of the IDE, but it works in PyCharm at least...

Answer (score 0):

A common way is to export a `APP_HOME` path in the execution enviroment( specific to Windows, Linux , or a IDE ). then in the application, load from `os.path.join( os.environ['APP_HOME'], 'some/path/dicotest.txt'))`